# Clickonce publish with expired certificate

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, clickonce

I have this error

> Error 32  An error occurred while signing: Failed to sign bin\Release\app.publish\setup.exe. SignTool Error: The signer's certificate is not valid for signing.
>   SignTool Error: An error occurred while attempting to sign: bin\Release\app.publish\setup.exe MyProject

My certificate expired in 8/23, I've tried to create a new certificate in the signing tab and everything is fine; but when I click publish I get this message:

> The application is signed with a different key than the existing application on the server. Do you want to overwrite it?

If I choose 'yes' the users could access the new application version without any certificate issues?

Comment: Ideally you need to test this. Do you have another place where this app is published? If so, instead of writing over the Production publishing directory you can write over a Test publishing directory. Then see how that works.

Answer (score 2):

According to Microsoft itself, if you are targeting .NET 4 or later "you can just replace your certificate, issue an update, and go to lunch while the rest of us struggle on."

[Certificate Expiration in ClickOnce Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff369721.aspx)