# Updating ClickOnce app with new certificate makes Windows think this is a different app

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2017, clickonce, .net-4.6.2

Similar posts that I've already seen but don't really address my issue:

- [ClickOnce certificate renew deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43935582/clickonce-certificate-renew-deploy) - User gets an error that I don't get.
- [How can I renew my expired ClickOnce certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280472/how-can-i-renew-my-expired-clickonce-certificate) - I can't renew my cert since its not a test certificate.
- [Clickonce publish with expired certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25854896/clickonce-publish-with-expired-certificate) - This one is pretty close, but the answer doesn't solve my problem, probably because the article mentioned is 9 years old and targets a different version of .NET.

I tried to ask this on [Microsoft](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7318238d-c32c-4c6d-8508-b7eda1fec666/cant-update-application-when-new-version-uses-new-certificate), but only got what seemed to be automated responses, so I'll try my luck here.

I purchased a certificate almost a year ago that I've been using to sign my ClickOnce deployed WinForms application. Since it's about to expire, I purchased a new one using the same data as before (although I accidentally used a different postal code; I'll mention this again below). I'm using a test web location to test publishing with the old certificate, and then publishing an update using the new certificate to see what the user experience would be. According to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/ff369721(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN), if I'm using VS 2010 and .NET 4.0, users should get the update normally. I use VS 2017 and .NET 4.6.2, so I guess this should also apply to my case.

Except that when I publish the update, I get this warning:

> The application is signed with a different key than the existing
>   application on the server. Do you want to overwrite it?

If I publish it anyway, I don't see any update prompt on the machine where the product is installed, and if I manually download and install the new version, it installs it side-by-side with the old one with a "- 1" appended to the product name. Which I think is what happens when you install two separate ClickOnce applications that have the same name. So Windows thinks this is a different application instead of an update to the existing one.

I opened up both the old and new generated manifest files (`MyApplication.exe.manifest`) and noted that the `publicKeyToken` differs in the `assemblyIdentity` element:

```
<asmv1:assemblyIdentity name="MyApplication.exe" version="1.2.3.4" publicKeyToken="44de2eab9d920cfd" language="neutral" processorArchitecture="amd64" type="win32" />
```

vs

```
<asmv1:assemblyIdentity name="MyApplication.exe" version="1.2.3.4" publicKeyToken="6fec920a5f1bbb2b" language="neutral" processorArchitecture="amd64" type="win32" />
```

Also, the `publisherIdentity` element contains different postal codes since I mistakingly used a different postal code on the old and new certificates (although I did ask support to use the same data everywhere regardless of what I typed, since I purchased both from the same vendor). These two differences don't exist when I compare two versions that use the same certificate.

So my question can be reduced to just two questions:

1. Does the `publicKeyToken` determine the identity of the application, such that if they are different, then Windows will treat them as separate applications (which would explain what is happening here)?
2. Is the `PostalCode` attribute of the `publisherIdentity` used to generate the `publicKeyToken` (which would explain why my publicKeyTokens are different)?

If both are yes then at least I'll know why exactly I'm having this problem and I guess there'd be hope that purchasing a new cert with the right postal code may solve it. But I don't want to purchase yet another cert just to see if that fixes it, so I wonder if anyone had some experience with this or some insight into how this aspect of ClickOnce works.

Comment: I haven't read all this, but the title seems promising: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/ff369721(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: @Flydog57 Yeah I saw that but it doesn't seem to work here. I also mentioned it on my post.

Comment: Oh, and public key tokens are simply shortened versions of the public key associated with the private key used to sign the assembly.  Take a look at @ericlippert's answer to this question for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321419/what-is-the-role-of-public-key-token.  Your postal code doesn't get involved at all.

Comment: And... Have you asked the CA you purchased the cert from if they can renew your initial cert (rather than getting a completely new one).  A simple search turned up this: https://docs.digicert.com/manage-certificates/code-signing-certificate/renew-code-signing-certificate/, which, to me, looks like there is at least one CA that will issue you a new cert (with new dates) based on the same key-pair